# Netbeans GUI Builder: how to edit generated code

Tags: java, user-interface, netbeans, jtree

Im using Netbeans GUI Builder and I am adding a JTree to my form, as it does Netbeans is generating all the code for the JTree.

What i want to know is, is there a way in Netbeans to add code to the generated code... like in the source view in the `Generated Code` section it creates

```
jTree = new javax.swing.JTree();
```

i want to add `populateJTree.addNodes(null, folder)` so it looks like

```
jTree = new javax.swing.JTree(populateJTree.addNodes(null, folder));
```

Is there a way of doing this

Answer (score 4, accepted):

i sorted it, if you go to the `Properties` window for the JTree and the `Code` section, you can add

`new javax.swing.JTree(populateJTree.addNodes(null, folder));`

to the custom creation code part and it will create

`jTree = new javax.swing.JTree(populateJTree.addNodes(null, folder));`

Answer (score 5):

Yes there is a way to add code. Just right click on the component (in this example it would be JTree) than choose "Customize code", select "custom creation" and you are good to go.

Answer (score 4):

1. open .java file in notepad.
2. now delete the lines above at initComponents() method,
   `@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
   // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">//GEN-BEGIN:initComponents`
   and in the end of initComponents() method, remove 
   `// </editor-fold>//GEN-END:initComponents`
3. And in the end of your .java file the is a variable declaration it also contain generated code remove it also,
   `// Variables declaration - do not modify//GEN-BEGIN:variables`
   and
   `// End of variables declaration//GEN-END:variables`
4. save the file from notepad.
5. now open net-beans
6. see now you can edit the Generated code.

   - if you want to get back your generated code to interact with design first save your file and then reverse the above process.*