# How to modify Netbeans Swing generated methods?

Tags: java, swing, netbeans

I use netbeans 7.3. I need to modify methods generated by the IDE. For example; I want to change the 'initComponents()' method's access level from private to protected. and some functions generated as private to protected? That means the following is a function generated by IDE with private modifier. I want to make it as protected void jButton4ActionPerfomrd(...

`private void jButton4ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {

        // TODO add your handling code here:
    }`

Any Suggession please?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10851468/netbeans-gui-builder-how-to-edit-generated-code

Comment: DUPLICATE : ? : By the option 'Customize Code', the COmponent related codes can be modified, but not functions. Therefore not a duplicate.

Comment: don't use the builder <tongue-in-cheek> Seriously: why do you want to open up the access? It's bad style to let subclasses override methods that are called inside the constructor.

Comment: Some time, some design concepts may not match every where and always. For my application design, I have required such requirement. how ever thanks kleoptatra for your info.

Answer (score -1):

Open the Java file on another editor. There you can change it manually, or even remove NetBeans "hidden marks" for uneditable parts of code - and edit everything in NetBeans itself.

But beware: then you can mess up things between code and GUI creator.